# Get absolute path in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can you get the absolute path in html.

If i use location.href i can get the url but how can i trim the filename.html ?

IS there a better way to get the path.

Thanks!

Comment: Get yourself a JavaScript reference: [MDN window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`location.pathname` gives you the local part of the url.

```
var filename = location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]
```

The above gives you only the very last part. For example, if you are on `http://somedomain/somefolder/filename.html`, it will give you `filename.html`

Comment: Add a  `[0]` after the match so that you extract the actual value. Otherwise you end with an array of matches (*only one in this case*)

Answer (score 7):

For this page if you inspect the `window.location` object you will see

```
hash:       
host:       stackoverflow.com
hostname:   stackoverflow.com
href:       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401879/get-absolute-path-in-javascript
pathname:   /questions/8401879/get-absolute-path-in-javascript
port:       
protocol:   http:
search:
```

[Documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties)

So `location.pathname` is what you want. And if you want to extract the last part use regex.

```
var lastpart = window.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var full = location.pathname;
var path = full.substr(full.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you need everything from protocol to last '/' you can use:

```
new RegExp('[^?]+/').exec(location.href)
```

and don't worry that it will match to the first '/' because '+' is a greedy quantifier, which means it will match as much as it can. First part '[^?]' is to stop matching before parameters because '/' can appear in parameter values like `t.php?param1=val1/val2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var loc = window.location.href;
var fileNamePart = loc.substr(loc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// "http://localhost:8080/public/help/index.html"
const loc = window.location.href;

// "http://localhost:8080/public/help/"
const path = loc.substr(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```